# cannot cast int *(*)[] to int(**)[]

Tags: c++, types, new-operator, allocation

```
int main()
{
    int j;
    std::cin >> i >> j;
    int (**ptr)[1];
    ptr = new (int*[i][1]);//error
    for (int index = 0;index < i;++index)
        ptr[index] = new (int[j][1]);
}
```

I have a compiler error.

Then, how can I allocate `int(**)[]`?

Comment: The easiest practical solution is to use a `std::vector` the manage the memory. If you insist on a DIY solution, then name the types involved. Naming things is almost always a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem.

Original code except that I've added the missing `#include` directive – to avoid wrong guesses about your code, and irrelevant issues being discussed, please do include *everything* in posted code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int j;
    std::cin >> i >> j;
    int (**ptr)[1];
    ptr = new (int*[i][1]);//error
    for (int index = 0;index < i;++index)
        ptr[index] = new (int[j][1]);
}
```

Compiling with MinGW g++ 5.1.0:

```
C:\my\forums\so\116> g++ --version | find "++"
g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0

C:\my\forums\so\116> g++ original.cpp
original.cpp: In function 'int main()':
original.cpp:5:17: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
     std::cin >> i >> j;
                 ^
original.cpp:9:35: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array [-Wvla]
         ptr[index] = new (int[j][1]);
                                   ^
original.cpp:9:36: error: non-constant array new length must be specified without parentheses around the type-id [-Wvla]
         ptr[index] = new (int[j][1]);
                                    ^

C:\my\forums\so\116> _
```

That compiler detected the following problems:

- Missing declaration of variable `i`.
- Inadvertent use of C99 **variable length array**, VLA, due to syntactical error.

Compiling with Visual C++ 2015 update 2:

```
C:\my\forums\so\116> cl /nologo- 2>&1 | find "++"
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23725 for x86

C:\my\forums\so\116> cl original.cpp
original.cpp
original.cpp(5): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier
original.cpp(7): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier
original.cpp(7): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'int *(*)[1]' to 'int (**)[1]'
original.cpp(7): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
original.cpp(8): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier

C:\my\forums\so\116> _
```

This compiler doesn't support C99 VLAs, and so instead diagnoses

- Incompatible types in pointer assignment.

Apparently this is the error message the OP is concerned about, but the OP reported it as

> **”** cannot cast int *(*)[] to int(**)[]

which is meaningless because one can indeed cast between data pointer types.

So,

- The error description in the question is incorrect.
- The code has issues (lacking include, lacking variable declaration) in addition to the error singled out by the OP.
- It's unclear what the code is meant to do, except in a very abstract sense that allowed advice such as “use a `std::vector`”.

However, the code snippet

```
for (int index = 0;index < i;++index)
    ptr[index] = new (int[j][1]);
```

***strongly indicates*** that this is an attempt to do a dynamic size matrix (2D array) of `int` values, with dimensions specified by the user, and I assume that in the following.

---

### Fix of the original code.

It often helps to *name things*. In this case, for clarity, we can name the `int*` type as `Int_array_ptr`. That indicates the intended usage: not as a pointer to a single `int`, but as a pointer to the first item of an array of `int`, i.e. as a pointer to the array.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int n_rows;
    int n_columns;
    std::cin >> n_rows >> n_columns;

    using Int_array_ptr = int*;
    Int_array_ptr* matrix;
    matrix = new Int_array_ptr[n_rows];     // An array of `n_rows` pointers.
    for( int i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i )
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[n_columns]();   // The `()` adds zero-initialization.
    }

    // At this point one can use it like `matrix[row][column] = 42`.
}
```

The resulting structure is called a **jagged array**, because it permits the column vectors to be of different lengths (here they're all the same length).

---

### How to do a matrix in general.

A good alternative to matrix-as-jagged-array is to use a single contiguous 1D array as storage, and just provide 2D indexing into this array.

A good to way to manage an array's storage is to use a `std::vector`.

And a good way to encapsulate an indexing operation plus other array stuff (or most any set of related operations on a common state) is to define a class.

So, this strongly suggests to define a class that provides a 2D indexing operation on a single 1D array whose storage is managed by a `std::vector`.

The indexing would ideally be via `operator[]`, but as a member operation it can only take 1 argument. And it's a bit of a bother to write e.g. `matrix[Location(3,58)]` instead of the ideal `matrix[3,58]` (which would be parsed as use of a comma expression). So, typically `operator()`, the function call operator, is used instead of `[]`.

It's possible to instead support the notation `matrix[3][58]`, but let's choose the conceptually simpler implementation of `operator()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_FAILURE
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:
    vector<int>     items_;
    int             n_columns_;

    auto index_of( int const row, int const col ) const
        -> int
    { return row*n_columns_ + col; }

public:
    auto operator()( int const row, int const col )
        -> int&
    { return items_[index_of( row, col )]; }

    auto operator()( int const row, int const col ) const
        -> int
    { return items_[index_of( row, col )]; }

    Matrix( int const n_rows, int const n_columns )
        : items_( n_rows*n_columns )
        , n_columns_( n_columns )
    {}
};

auto main() -> int
{
    int n_rows;
    int n_columns;
    std::cin >> n_rows >> n_columns;
    if( cin.fail() ) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    Matrix matrix( n_rows, n_columns );
    // At this point one can use it like `matrix( row, column ) = 42`.
}
```

This is far more code than the original, but

- it's *reusable* code, which saves work,
- it's more robust code, with the difficult things (memory management) automated, and
- it can even be more efficient, because it manages with a single dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

you have allocate an pointer array, and then each element(pointer) points to an array like

```
int i = 20, j = 40;

int** ptr = new int*[i];

for (int a = 0; a < i; a++) {
    ptr[a] = new int[j];
    // ...
    delete [] ptr[a];
}
delete [] ptr;
```

**EDIT**

back to your code

when you define a type E as int[1];

```
int j, i;
std::cin >> i >> j;
typedef int E[1];
E **ptr;                                // int (**ptr)[1];
ptr = new E*[i];                        // ptr = new (int*[i][1]);//error
for (int index = 0;index < i;++index)
    ptr[index] = new E[j];              // ptr[index] = new (int[j][1]);
```

so just a pointer to pointer of integer, not like what you said

Comment: I want to allocate a pointer of pointer of array, not pointer of pointer

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to allocate 2-D array. So the allocation should be done as:

```
int i, j;       // Initialize some value to i, j.
....
int **ptr = new int*[i];
for(int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    ptr[k] = new int[j];
}
```

This will make a 2-D array that has i rows and j columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allocate an array of `int (*)[1]` objects. You've already noticed that syntax like `new int(*)[1]` doesn't work because it is parsed as `new int` followed by the function call operator, so you have to use the `new(T)` form.

Also, `int *[i][1]` is not right, because `int *` is pointer-to-int. Much like you did in `int (**ptr)[1]`, you have to use parentheses to break the `*` from the `int`.

So the right syntax for this *would be* `new( int (*[i])[1] )`. But unfortunately, the `new(T)` form is not allowed to contain non-constant expressions inside the parentheses!

*Technical information:* There is a dedicated grammar (C++14 [dcl.name]/1) for the cases `sizeof(T)`, `alignof(T)`, `new(T)` and `typeid(T)` and casts; and it only permits square brackets to be empty or contain a *constant-expression* inside the square brackets.  There is another separate grammar for the `new T` case ([expr.new]/1)  (which knows about `[]` but not `()`, and allows non-constant expressions), and both of these are separate to the grammar for parsing declarators in other situations.

So the only solution to this (while retaining the type of `ptr`) is to use a typedef:

```
typedef int Arr1[1];
ptr = new Arr1 *[i];
```

Each row is:

```
ptr[index] = new int[j][1];    // or "new Arr1[j];"
```

Comment: Note: obviously there are other ways to solve the same problem, my answer just addresses the syntax of this particular approach.

Comment: Formally, the parenthesized form has a simple `type_id` instead of a `new_type_id`. However, Visual C++ appears to treat it as `new_type_id`. I would guess that the formal has to do with distinguishing a placement new argument as such.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf added a para going into a bit more detail about that

Comment: MSVC implements VLA in C++, so I suppose they rolled their own rules and this is one of the side-effects of that.

Comment: I wanted answer like this, but I have another question : is it recommended not to code like this?

Comment: @LeeSongUn well - it is fairly uncommon, and more complicated than necessary; and also it is not exception-safe. You should use RAII to make your code simpler and safer. As Alf mentioned, `vector<vector<int>>` has the same memory layout as your `new`s but fixes those problems;  and you may be able to solve your problem by using a contiguous buffer instead, which will perform better.  See the other answers for advice along those lines.